# What can replace google-maps infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2

I used google-maps infowindow, but I can't manage with infowindow padding,and now my tab looks like [image]

but i need black content div align all white tab length,I read in the documentation that I cna't customize google infoWindow, and they offer to use popup,but I need to show it only on hover. On project I use vue.js maybe smb have experience what and how to use instead infoWindow with vue?

```
getDevelopmentInInfoWindow(entity, marker) {
      window.axios.get(`/development-map/development/${entity.id}`)
           .then((response) => {
                this.instance.$props.entity = response.data;
                this.instance.$mount();
              this.infoWindow.setContent(this.instance.$el.innerHTML);

                    this.infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
                })
                .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        },
        initializeInfoWindow() {
            let InfoWindow = Vue.extend(InfoWindowComponent);

            this.instance = new InfoWindow({
                propsData: {
                    entity: null,
                }
            });

            this.infoWindow = new this.google.maps.InfoWindow({
                shadow: false,
            });
        },
```

Comment: Please share the codes in the question.

Comment: @Raptor updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use the [custom popup](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-popup)

This is the alternative if you would like to make adjustments in the infowindow like style because infowindow class does not offer customization, so changing the style of the infowindow class is not recommended.

There is also an example included in the docs for your reference.